# LibVLC 3.x how to open stream described by SDP file or stream containing credentials

Tags: c++, libvlc

Im using libVLC to playback video in my application,

to open local files im using:
libvlc_media_new_path(path_to_file);

to open stream im using:

libvlc_media_new_location(media_location)

it works for most stream addresses, but

i can't play streams containing SDP file in address, for example:

http://192.168.10.17/live.sdp (its stream in my local network)

also i can't player stream containing credentials like

rtsp://user:user123@192.168.10.156:8081

VLC application can play both stream without sweat.

So anyone knows how to open sdp file using libVLC and how to open stream with credentials in address in libVLC?
am i missing any methods?

thanks

Comment: I use the same format as you describe and it works successfully.  Your problem may be elsewhere.  Have you tried implementing logging via libvlc_log_set?  It may report why your connection is failing.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, when you don't know how to do something with LibVLC, but you know how to it with the VLC app (and it works), open the logging windows (Tools => Messages), enable debug logging and reproduce your operation. The logs will tell you a story.

Now for authentication matters, I think you can provide the credentials directly in the URL (see how VLC does it, from the logs) and you can also probably implement [libvlc_dialog_post_login](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__dialog.html#ga7ebafe2ac8fc82ebe6dd8d4dab36d0c7) which is raised by LibVLC when auth creds are required.